# When does the GitHub Gist API rate limit reset?

Tags: github, github-api, gist

I'm making unauthenticated calls to the GitHub Gist API, and I've exceeded the rate limit. Trying to browse to https://api.github.com/users/seisvelas/gists?page=1&per_page=100, I receive:

```
{
  "message": "API rate limit exceeded for 187.188.105.159. (But here's the good news: Authenticated requests get a higher rate limit. Check out the documentation for more details.)",
  "documentation_url": "https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting"
}
```

I browsed to the suggested [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting), and it suggested I take a look at the `X-RateLimit-Reset:` response header, so I did. My response headers look like this:

```
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 0
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1566344009
```

Okay, so I'm allowed 60 requests. But the time for the Rate Limit Reset is given as `1566344009`...units. I'm not sure what these units are measured in. Milliseconds? If so, that would mean I'm allowed 60 requests every ~18 days. Which seems a bit conservative but not out of the question, but I'd prefer to know for sure what unit the rate limit time is being measured in.

I didn't see any suggestions on the documentation, so any help is immensely appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer did turn out to be on the docs, don't know how I missed it! It represents the Unix epoch time in seconds. When the time reaches that epoch time, you're rate limit resets. In my case, `1566344009` in [Unix Epoch Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) represents Tuesday, August 20, 2019 11:33:29 PM, GMT.

If you have a time given in Unix Epoch Time and want to convert it to GMT or local time, here is the tool I used to do so:

https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: This makes sense but I am seeing a value of `"X-RateLimit-Reset": "1670567917"` which is November 28, 2022 and today is December 8, 2022.